# ansible and reloading AWS dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003420/reload-ansibles-dynamic-inventory.

**My question:** is there a better way of doing what's below?

I have an ansible role that provisions AWS machines, and runs correctly (notice the `provision` tag):

```
- name: AWS provision
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vars/dev.yml
  user: ec2-user
  roles:
    - provision
  tags:
    - provision
```

I then have a `base` role, that I want to be able to run independently (for example during development, so I don't have to wait for re-provisioning (notice the `base` tag). I run a play `find running instances` that filters and stores the hosts in the group `started`:

```
- name: find running instances
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - vars/dev.yml
  gather_facts: no
  tags:
    - base
  tasks:
    - name: gather remote facts
      ec2_remote_facts:
        region: "{{ target_aws_region }}"
        filters:
          instance-state-name: running
          "tag:Name": "{{ instance_name }}"
      register: ec2_facts

    - debug: var=ec2_facts

    - name: add hosts to groups
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.id }}"
        ansible_ssh_host: "{{ item.public_dns_name }}"
        groups: started
      changed_when: false
      with_items: ec2_facts.instances

- name: base setup
  hosts: started
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vars/dev.yml
  user: ec2-user
  roles:
    - base
  tags:
    - base
```

**My question:** the plays are working, but is there a better way of doing this? For example I'm got `gather_facts: no` followed by `ec2_remote_facts` and the `filters` - it all seems rather convoluted.

**A clarification:** thanks for the comment about `ec2.py` -- I'm already using it in my first play (when I call the `provision` role).

But for testing purposes I want to jump into subsequent plays without re-doing the (slow) provisioning. So *how do I re-populate my hosts data?* Is `ec2_remote_facts` followed by `add_host` the right way? Or can I somehow use `gather_facts: yes`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably use the EC2 dynamic inventory script instead, which you can employ by configuring `ec2.ini` and passing `-i ec2.py` to `ansible-playbook`.

See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script for more info.

Note that there are plenty of options in `ec2.ini`. Be sure to have a look at those, e.g. `cache_max_age`. You can also make the inventory generation faster by filtering unnecessary resources (e.g. set `rds = False` if you are only interested in EC2 instances).

**UPDATE:** With Ansible 2.x+ you can also use `- meta: refresh_inventory` mid-play.

Comment: Why do you run a play to find the instances "programmatically" when you can just use the ec2 inventory to find the instances e.g. by tags? Note the cache property I mentioned. You can set it to zero to have a fresh inventory for each run (if the first provision run leaves you with an empty inventory since the instances have not been provisioned yet at the start of the run).

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand :-) How do I get ec2.py to populate the inventory when I jump in halfway through a play, without setting cache to zero? Use "gather_facts: true" and just filter on the tags?

Comment: Either run the second play separately and empty cache in-between or use Ansible 2.x's `- meta: refresh_inventory`. If you choose to empty the ec2.py cache, you might want to tweak its settings to filter as much as possible (i.e. everything but the ec2 instances you are interested in) to make it faster.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @jukka. I didn't know about `meta: refresh_inventory`.

Comment: Glad to help, I updated my answer for future readers as well.

Answer (score 2):

While the `meta: refresh_inventory` is the "preferred method", I tend to like OP's proposal of using `ec2_remote_facts` in conjunction with `add_host`. I've setup such a playbook and it has the strength to be 100% dynamic without caching glitches.

Assuming your *ASG* fired up instances with the `env: cool_asg_instance` tag, just add the following under the `ec2_asg` playbook call:

```
- ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
      "tag:env": "cool_asg_instance"
  register: instance_facts
```

You'll then gather a full *JSON* dataset containing all the needed informations, from there you can use `Jinja2` capabilities within the playbook to extract newly created IP addresses, i.e.:

```
- name: group hosts
  add_host: hostname={{ item }} groups=launched
  with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances|selectattr('state', 'equalto', 'running')|map(attribute='private_ip_address')|list }}"
```

Filter is courtesy of this wonerfull blog post: https://bonovoxly.github.io/2016-02-11-ansible-stuffs-ec2_remote_facts_instead_of_ec2_py

From now on you can use the `launched` group on your parent deployment *YAML* file like this:

```
- hosts: launched
  gather_facts: no

  tasks: 
    - name: wait for SSH
      wait_for: port=22 host="{{ inventory_hostname }}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=5
```

Some may ask why the headache, well imagine that instead of having an hideous `userdata` which will `git clone` both Ansible and a playbook from the Internet, you can trigger the instance setup from your own deployment center by setting up a simple *SNS* topic which will publish to a *SQS* queue, watched by a 10 lines python code (https://github.com/alexandregama/python-sqs-consumer/blob/master/sqs-message-consumer-polling.py) which will trigger Ansible when a new instance comes out.

Comment: Just confirming - When you say "_ASG_", you're referring to an [AWS Auto-Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html), correct?

Comment: Yes, _ASG_ is a shorthand for Auto Scaling Group

Answer (score 0):

I found this was easier than I expected. The following code allows you to run playbooks against existing AWS inventory, which is what I originally want to do. Based on [1] and [2].

(my solution is a bit more flexible eg custom `ansible.cfg` & `ssh_config`)

Setup ansible config file and use it:

```
% cat ./ansible.cfg.foo
[defaults]
hostfile = inventory
host_key_checking = false
private_key_file = bar.pem
remote_user = ec2-user
ssh_args = -F ./ssh_config

export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=ansible.cfg.foo
```

Optionally setup custom ssh config, so your laptop's settings don't interfere. ssh config could also be done in `ansible.cfg.foo`, but I like having it separate so an existing `~/.ssh/config` can be used by third parties.

```
% cat ./ssh_config
StrictHostKeyChecking no
...
```

Run your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook config.yml --tags base
```

Where playbook might look like the following. aws tags (eg `tag_env_test`) are used to select hosts.

```
% cat config.yml
- name: base setup
  hosts:
    - tag_env_test
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - vars/qux.yml
  roles:
    - base
  tags:
    - base

- name:  java setup
  hosts:
  ...
```

I use `./ec2.py --list > ../ec2_output.txt` to investigate hosts I'm interested in selecting.

I've marked Jukka's answer as the solution, to thank him for helping :-)

[1] http://www.slideshare.net/bfschott/using-ansible-dynamic-inventory-with-amazon-ec2

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/